# Use FFMPEG on videos and not create tags

Tags: ffmpeg, tags, duration, encoder

I sometimes use ffmpeg to reencode certain MKV files.  I've got the reencoding working great, the only problem I have is that ffmpeg generates Global Tags and Tags.  It's not *really* a problem, but just extra stuff that I'd like to get rid of.  Using MKVINFO, I find the name of the tags it creates are ENCODER (for both video and audio tracks) and DURATION (for video, audio and subtitle tracks). For example:

```
|+ Tags
| + Tag
|  + Targets
|  + Simple
|   + Name: ENCODER
|   + String: Lavf58.41.100
| + Tag
|  + Targets
|   + Track UID: 1
|  + Simple
|   + Name: ENCODER
|   + String: Lavc58.75.100 h264_amf
| + Tag
|  + Targets
|   + Track UID: 1
|  + Simple
|   + Name: DURATION
|   + String: 00:52:41.867000000
| + Tag
|  + Targets
|   + Track UID: 2
|  + Simple
|   + Name: DURATION
|   + String: 00:52:41.888000000
| + Tag
|  + Targets
|   + Track UID: 3
|  + Simple
|   + Name: DURATION
|   + String: 00:50:06.421000000
```

I can get rid of these tags using MKVPROPEDIT, but I'd just like to not create them in the first place.  Any help?